# FB Graph API - Get pictures which I liked

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I searched for myself almost 2 hours, but I did not find any solution. Maybe you can help.

The Issue:
I went to http://www.mammut.ch/de/productDetail/101013950_v_5268_L/Nordwand-Pro-Jacket-Men.html and liked the product at the end of the page via the like button.
The product now appears in my activity feed. Norman likes , with description, URL and image.

If I now query the graph api with /me/likes I receive ALL THE FB PAGES I liked. But I do not receive the liked product. I tried out almost any GraphAPI Connection, but I was not able to receive the product from my activity feed.
I think the major difference is, that this actually is not a like, like a like on FB-Company/Band Page. But what is it, and how is it possible to receive these kind of information.

Thanks alot in advance.